# Prevent input from negative number Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is there are any rule that could prevent posting `number type input` with negative number ? This is my price schema:

```
price: {
    type: Number,
    trim: true,
    default: "0.00"
},
```

Maybe there is like minvalue or something ? That would be really helpful.

Comment: min: 0, worked!

Comment: What is your modeling engine? Mongoose? Sequelize? mysql? MongoDB? something else?

Comment: @wlh it's Mongoose

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's a mongoose schema , if so you would need :`min:0`